# Why there is a useless(in my thought) dup2 in CgLib BeanCopier

Tags: java, jvm, java-bytecode-asm, cglib, jvm-bytecode

BeanCopier of cglib use the method net.sf.cglib.beans.BeanCopier.Generator#generateClass to get a specific BeanCopier according to the clazz you give. but at line 152 of BeanCopier.java, there is a useless dup2 which I think there. I made my own BeanCopier just remove the line 152, the rest part of it is as same as CGLIB BeanCopier.java, and my copier is is still working without any Exception or Error.
There is bytecode that Cglib BeanCopier.java generated

```java
public void copy(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, net.sf.cglib.core.Converter);
    Code:
       0: aload_2
       1: checkcast     #13                 // class study/copierTest/B
       4: aload_1
       5: checkcast     #15                 // class study/copierTest/A
       8: dup2
       9: invokevirtual #19                 // Method study/copierTest/A.getA:()Ljava/lang/String;
      12: invokevirtual #23                 // Method study/copierTest/B.setA:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      15: return
```

Mine Copier is just without the dup2 and still working.

So, My Question is: Is the dup2 truly useless, or I missed some circumstances that the dup2 is useful？

PS: I'm not familiar with java bytecode, so I'm sorry if i ask something silly.

Answer (score 2):

This is only an educated guess, but it is very likely that the code generator supports an arbitrary number of properties, so `dup2` ensures that the two bean references remain on stack for the next property.

In that case, the code generator generates the `dup2` instruction for *every* property. It could be omitted for the *last* property (which is the *only* property in your case), but that would require special treatment of the last element when processing the property descriptors and generating the code, for the sake of only saving one byte in the resulting class file. So this optimization was not made.

Comment: Thanks, I missed this arbitrary number of properties circumstance, and I probably found why bean copier is mush faster than pure get/set. it use `dup2` to ensures that the two bean references remain on stack, the pure get/set will load the parameter again. Am I right?

Comment: It depends on how the alternative, you’re comparing with, has been implemented. The code of your question receives two `Object`s and performs a type cast for each, then reuses the result via `dup2`, so it does not need to repeat the type casts. You could achieve the same by storing the result into two local variables, but this would require two `aload` instructions per property instead of a single `dup2`. I wouldn’t expect a significant performance difference between the stack and local variable variant though. But a variant repeating the type cast might be slower.

Comment: Even if the JIT is able to optimize a version using temporary locals to perform equivalently to a version using `dup2`, a version using `dup2` may perform differently in practice simply because the method will be smaller and more eagerly inlined.  Whether it would be _faster_ would depend on what your call tree looks like.  While I find smaller methods are generally preferable, don't read too much into that; as Holger says, the difference would likely be imperceptible.